# Is the quote 'Meet me behind [name of guide]'s house in three hours.' From the traveling merchant true?

Tags: terraria-mobile

In Terraria, the Traveling Merchant has a chance to say 'Meet me behind [Name of guide]'s house in three hours.  I have something you may find appealing.' Does this quote actually signal an event, or is it a complete fake?

Comment: Hey man, your original post had a spelling error bad enough I'm not 100% sure what you meant. I've edited the question to be my best guess at what was intended. If I guessed wrong please edit it again.

Comment: @Fambida Thankyou for the edit! I'm not very good at explaining things. I bet that cleared it up a little ^_^

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### It's just flavor text

All NPCs have various things they will say when you open the dialog box with them, and sometimes their lines will reference interactions with other NPCs. However, none of it has any actual significance to the game, and none of these interactions actually happen. The line in question is simply [a random quote the Traveling Merchant says](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Traveling_Merchant#Quotes).